# Asking for time arrangement

Tags: time

I would like to meet my lecturer in August. I want to send an email to her. 
Is this sentence correct:

> When will you be free in August?

I want to know if that's the correct way to ask for an appointment in English.

Comment: I would suggest that, in future questions, you add a sentence or two explaining why you're unsure that your suggested version is incorrect. I think this question is a legitimate one, but ELL frowns on questions that seem like they are asking for open-ended proofreading. Had you explained more about your doubts (something like, "Is this a correct usage of *free*"?), the question may not have had any close votes. In any case, I hope the one answer you got was helpful; welcome to the community.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's nothing really incorrect about your sentence. We can ask about "being free" when we want to know if someone has an opening in their schedule.

That said, I do have a suggestion. When trying to arrange an appointment, there are two things to consider: the day, and the time. For example, I might have an opening on August 4, but only in the afternoon.

So, rather than saying "When will you be free in August," I might be more specific, and ask:

> What times will you be free in August?

Or, I might even say:

> What times in August would be good for you?

Using "what times" instead of "when" might steer the person into giving you a more specific time of day, instead of just a list of days. If I was looking for days and not times, I might word it this way instead:

> What days in August are you available?

That said, I want to reemphasize: I'm only writing some additional examples to help you better understand the various ways this question can be asked in English. There's nothing wrong with the question as you've worded it.